# AR process stationarity

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, autoregressive, signal-processing

For $X[n] =aX[n-1]+W[n]$
When $W[n]$ is iid. 
One can say that $X[n]$ is the output of $W[n]$ thrown into an LTI system. 
So how can it be that $X[n]$ is not necessarily WSS, if we know that a WSS threw LTI system must be wss output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LTI filter is stable, then the output random process is WSS, as well as it is jointly WSS with the input process, such that their cross-correlation is defined and depends on a single parameter. For example, consider the case where $a=10^{385}$, would you consider what you'll be plotting as stationary?

Comment: I understand your point. But isn't it a contradiction to the lti thing? That the input and output are jwss?

Comment: No, it's not a contradiction. Some sources ignore to say that the filter should be stable. Throwing an input, even a stationary one, into an unstable filter and expecting stationary output is not reasonable.

Comment:  It wasn't on my textbooks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlmogCarmeli think of your filter as a bomb :) you're welcome!